# populate SQL database with dask dataframe and dump into a file

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-dataframe

reproduce the error and the use case on [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ynvOxOm3Kbf_qW7xJa-_glp_iMFi9Plc?usp=sharing)

I have multiple large tables that I read and analyze through Dask (dataframe). After doing analysis, I would like to push them into a local database (in this case sqlite engine through sqlalchemy package.

here is a dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"i": i, "s": str(i) * 2} for i in range(4)])

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

from dask.utils import tmpfile
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

with tmpfile(
    dir="/outputs/",
    extension="db",
) as f:
    print(f)

    db = f"sqlite:///{f}"

    ddf.to_sql("test_table", db)

    engine = create_engine(
        db,
        echo=False,
    )

    print(dir(engine))
    result = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table").fetchall()

print(result)
```

however, the `tmpfile` is temporary and is not stored on my local drive. I would like to dump the database into my local drive; I could not find any argument for `tmpfile` to ensure it is stored as a file. Neither could figure out how to dump my engine.

***Update***
if I use a regular file, I will encounter the following error

```
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

here is the code

```
with open(
    "/outputs/hello.db", "wb"
) as f:
    print(f)

    db = f"sqlite:///{f}"

    ddf.to_sql("test_table", db, if_exists="replace")

    engine = create_engine(
        db,
        echo=False,
    )

    print(dir(engine))
    result = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table").fetchall()

print(result)
```

Comment: @python_user thanks for raising this up; I have tried but gives an error due to the way dask writes the data. you can have a look at the tmpfile https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/_modules/dask/utils.html with the contextmanager decorator.

Comment: It's not clear why using a regular file does not work for you. Can you elaborate on the error you see?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I updated the question with what you asked for. thanks

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev you can reproduce here on colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ynvOxOm3Kbf_qW7xJa-_glp_iMFi9Plc?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to save to a regular file, there is no need to use the context manager:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"i": i, "s": str(i) * 2} for i in range(4)])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)


OUT_FILE = "test.db"
db = f"sqlite:///{OUT_FILE}"

ddf.to_sql("test_table", db)
```

To test that the file is saved, run:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
    db,
    echo=False,
)

result = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table").fetchall()

print(result)
# [(0, 0, '00'), (1, 1, '11'), (2, 2, '22'), (3, 3, '33')]
```

Comment: Awesome - Thanks; perhaps the documentation can be updated then ?!

Comment: Let's try to do this via https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/9823